# What is throttling max concurrent connections? IIS? Windows Server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, iis, iis-7, asp.net

I have an asp.net app deployed on IIS, and have recently upgraded CPU and memory to double what it was in hopes that more concurrent users would be supported. Still though in my load test it seems like the server cannot handle even 100 concurrent connections. Furthermore, looking at the CPU and memory, only about 40% of the resources are being used during the load test! Is there some place on the server, or in IIS, or in the machine.config where the number of concurrent connections that the server will take at a time is limited? I have added this to web.config:

```
<system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
        <add address="*" maxconnection="65535"/>
    </connectionManagement>
</system.net>
```

And this to machine.config:

```
<processModel enable="true" timeout="00:03:00" requestLimit="Infinite" requestQueueLimit="Infinite" maxWorkerThreads="10000" maxIoThreads="10000"/>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "handle a connection?"  Are connection requests past 100 receiving a 503.2 error?  See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2007/07/21/asp-net-thread-usage-on-iis-7-0-and-6-0.aspx

Comment: Basically, when I ramp my test up to about 100 concurrent users I start getting ridiculous page times and a lot of Timeout errors. This to me means that my site cannot handle more than 100 or even a consistent 100 users. What I am trying now is increasing the number of worker processors, since CPU, memory, and bandwidth do not increase past about half of their potential during the load test. To make this work I have to configure SQL Session. If my theory is right, an increase in worker processors should resolve this issue.

Comment: you need to determine where the timeouts are occurring.  Incrementing worker threads for IIS isn't going to help if you are having a SQL timeout issue or your app is performing slowly due to a high disk IO operation or something similar.  Consider doing a SQL trace or profiling your app: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s0xxa1d.aspx